# Unable to stop instance in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am developing a java web application and deploying to Amazon EC2. I have deployed with default micro small ec-2 server. Now i have to move this ec-2 server from small to large server. I have gone through amazon document in that they said to stop the running instance and we can change the instance size. I have followed those steps. But problem is when i try to stop the instance, instance gets terminated and new instance with same name is launched.

Please help me..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using spot instances? You have to cancel your spot request or it'll keep relaunching.

Comment: spot instances means?

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/

Comment: Did you use elastic beanstalk to create your original instance?

Answer (score 0):

From the description you are providing, this instance may be part of an Auto Scaling Group either directly or through Elastic Beanstalk.  If it is in an Auto Scaling Group, your Launch Configuration needs to be updated.